Getting ZipException on aws lambda logs while processing the zip file through springboot apu
When i deploy my springboot application on aws lambda, and when i try to run the api which checks the zip file contents and store it in mongodb it gives byte code not a simple string below is the service method.
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> deployProduct(MultipartFile file, Map<String, String> headers) {
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    String message = "";
    boolean isEvenRaised = false;
    try {
        String token = headers.get(ProdInConstants.AUTHORIZATION);
        System.out.println(token);
        Map<String, String> userInfo = getRole(token);

        // specify roles which roles to allow
        if (userInfo.size() > 0
                && userInfo.get(ProdInConstants.ROLE).equalsIgnoreCase(ProdInConstants.ADMIN)) {

            MongoCollection<Document> collection = storageServiceManager
                    .getCollection(IStorageConstants.DEPLOYEMENT_COLLECTION);
            if (collection != null) {
                try (InputStream fis = file.getInputStream();
                        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

                    ZipEntry entry;
                    while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                        
                        String entryName = entry.getName();

                        System.out.println("Original Entry Name: " + entryName);
                        if (!entry.isDirectory()
                                && entry.getName().endsWith(ProdInConstants.XMLEXTENSION)) {

                            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            IOUtils.copy(zipInputStream, outputStream);
                            String xmlContent = outputStream.toString(ProdInConstants.UTF);

                            String hash = computeHash(xmlContent);

                            String[] pathComponents = entry.getName().split("/");
                            String ProductName = pathComponents[4];
                            String PlanName = pathComponents[5];
                            String formatterPlanName = "";
                            if (PlanName.endsWith(ProdInConstants.XMLEXTENSION)) {
                                formatterPlanName = PlanName.replace(ProdInConstants.XMLEXTENSION, "");
                                if (formatterPlanName.startsWith(".")) {
                                    formatterPlanName = formatterPlanName.replace(".", "");
                                    System.out.println(formatterPlanName);
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println(formatterPlanName);

                            // Save XML content to MongoDB
                            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                            boolean deployedPlan = productRepository.isXMLContentExist(collection, hash);
                            if (deployedPlan) {

                                message = "Plan with plan name "+formatterPlanName+" and product name "+ProductName+" is already existed.";
                                messages.add(message);
                                
                            } else {
                                    
                                try {
                                    
                                    Document existingProduct = productRepository.existingProduct(collection, formatterPlanName, ProductName);
                                    
                                    MongoCollection<Document> collectionHistory = storageServiceManager
                                            .getCollection(IStorageConstants.DEPLOYEMENT_HISTORY_COLLECTION);
                                    
                                    if (existingProduct != null) {

                                        Document documentToInsert = new Document(existingProduct);
                                        documentToInsert.remove("_id"); // Remove the _id field
                                        collectionHistory.insertOne(documentToInsert);

                                        collection.findOneAndDelete(Filters.eq(ProdInConstants.UUID,
                                                existingProduct.get(ProdInConstants.UUID)));

                                        existingProduct = new Document(ProdInConstants.PLAN_NAME,
                                                formatterPlanName).append(ProdInConstants.UUID, uuid)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.XML_CONTENT, xmlContent)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.PRODUCT_NAME, ProductName)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.HASH, hash)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.VERSION,
                                                        existingProduct.getLong(ProdInConstants.VERSION)
                                                                + 1);

                                        InsertOneResult insertOne = collection.insertOne(existingProduct);

                                        if (insertOne.getInsertedId() != null) {
                                            message = "Product with product name " + ProductName
                                                    + " deployed Successfully";
                                            messages.add(message);
                                            isEvenRaised = true;
                                        }

                                    }else {
                                        
                                        Document document = new Document(ProdInConstants.PLAN_NAME,
                                                formatterPlanName).append(ProdInConstants.UUID, uuid)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.XML_CONTENT, xmlContent)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.PRODUCT_NAME, ProductName)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.HASH, hash)
                                                .append(ProdInConstants.VERSION, new Long(1));

                                        InsertOneResult insertOne = collection.insertOne(document);

                                        if (insertOne.getInsertedId() != null) {
                                            message = "Product deployed Successfully";
                                            messages.add(message);
                                            isEvenRaised = true;
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    message = "something went wrong with plan "+formatterPlanName;
                                    messages.add(message);
                                    insertEvent(uuid, ProductName, formatterPlanName, userInfo, messages);
                                    return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                                }

                            } 
                            insertEvent(uuid, ProductName, formatterPlanName, userInfo, messages);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(isEvenRaised) {
                    //dummmy message
                    JSONObject person1 = new JSONObject();
                    person1.put("name", "John Doe");
                    person1.put("age", 30);
                    person1.put("city", "New York");
                    
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    jsonArray.add(person1);
                    eventServiceConfiguration.postMessage(jsonArray);
                }
                    
                return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                message = "something went wrong";
                messages.add(message);
                return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        } else {
            message = "User is not authorized to perform this task.";
            messages.add(message);
            return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

below is the logs

Original Entry Name: varfiles/.DS_Store?MJ?@???N!?.?I??A??(b?.Tj?
???vQ

below line in code
System.out.println("Original Entry Name: " + entryName);
is give varfiles/.DS_Store on local but on aws lambda it is giving a long byte code.
please help me here i'm stuck from last 2 days.
